# do i have to pay taxes if i own a business in mexico and live in the usa?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, mexico

i own a hardware store in mexico and pay my taxes in Mexico every two months because of the fiscal regimen im at(small business. Im a us citizen and i need to start paying my taxes in the usa also,who can process my taxes or how can i do them?

Comment: Is your question "Do I have to pay taxes?" or "How can I do them?" If it's the latter, it's probably not on topic because it's asking for a service or software recommendation, so choose the former :-), but make that clear in the question as well as the title. And as a US citizen living in the US, the answer to "Do I have to pay taxes?" is certainly "yes", but I'll leave it to someone smarter than me to say what sort of taxes and how owning the store in Mexico factors in.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you could either head down to the office supply store and pick up a copy of a tax program, or you could head over to the IRS office and pick up the instructions and forms.

However, in your case you should be talking to a tax lawyer.  The unfiled taxes are bad enough but you own a business outside the USA and most likely have bank accounts also.  That brings you into the realm of FATCA.

Comment: No need a tax lawyer, a decent CPA/EA will suffice. But a "tax software" for DUI taxes will definitely **not** be enough. None of the retail software supports all the required forms in this case (unless the business is pass-through in Mexico).

Comment: @littleadv Going forward there's no reason for a tax lawyer, I'm saying he needs one to fix his failure to file the FATCA reports.  I've never looked at the business-ownership side of FATCA, the asset reporting isn't that bad.

Comment: @littleadv DUI taxes? Taxing while drunk?